# Asia delights or Asian delights

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases, expressions

Should I use which one as a name of a restaurant promotion? In the menu we offer a range of Asian cuisine dishes.

Answer (score 1):

Asian delights.

Delight can be used as a verb, so Asia delights sounds like the beginning of a sentence... "Asia delights in its economic growth."